# Confused on Error Handling in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, error-handling

I got confused error handling in swift3. I try to do like  "if XX function got error then try YY function"
Let me show you what I try:

```
    class MyClass {
      enum error: Error
      {
        case nilString
      }
      func findURL() {
            do {
                let opt = try HTTP.GET(url_adr!)
                opt.start { response in
                    if let err = response.error {
                        print("error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                        return //also notify app of failure as needed
                    }
                    do
                    {
/* This is func1. and got error. I want to if this function has error then go next function. */
                            try self.stringOperation(data: response.description)
                        }
                        catch{
                            print("doesn't work on func1. trying 2nd func")
                          self.stringOperation2(data:response.descritption)
                        }

                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
                }
         }
         func stringOperation(data:String)throws -> Bool{
                do{
/** 1 **/
                        if let _:String = try! data.substring(from: data.index(of: "var sources2")!){ 
                            print("its done")
                        }else{
                        throw error.nilString
             }
```

IN 1: I got this fatal error on this line:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" and program crashed.
I googled error handling try to understand and apply to in my code. However not succeed yet. Can someone explain where did I wrong?

Additional info: I got String extension for .substring(from:...) , and .index(of:"str"). So these lines doesn't got you confused.

Comment: give the line number where the program crashed or found nil

Comment: error line is below of the "/** 1 **/ " messages...However tbogosia's answer is solved... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, try avoiding using force unwrapping (!), where you have

```
if let _: String= try! data.substring...
```

Instead use

```
if let index = data.index(of: "var sources2"), 
    let _: String = try? data.substring(from: index) { ... } else { ... }
```

That way you remove the two force unwraps that may be causing your crash. You already have the `if let` protection for catching the nil value, so you can make the most of it by using the conditional unwrapping.